# eBay Developer Sandbox Auth Token

Tags: ebay-api

I have an issue with generating a sandbox auth token, I get redirected the following link:

https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ThirdPartyAuthSucessFailure&ebaytkn=&tknexp=1970-01-01+00%3A00%3A00&username=testuser_jdawg)

once the request grant the application permission.

Which states the following message:

```
Thank YouHelp
Authorization cancelled
It's now safe to close the browser window/tab.
```

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: The third part auth success / failure piece seems weird.  Are you trying to generate auth keys for a different ebay account?  (IE linking an app to a client's account, not your own).

Comment: If so, I have not had that specific issue, but generating auth tokens for other accounts (ie logging into dev account and subsequently logging into the user account to generate the token) was really flaky for me.  I had to do it 7 or 8 times to get 3 tokens.

Comment: I have worked it out. Apparently to get this response is normal, then you send a Fetch Token request from the app to get the final token.

Comment: @jdawg can you please share how you solved this in a new answer to this question? I am having the same problem in sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

The ebay URL redirect after authentication is somewhat broken.

The default URL redirects are:

- On Success: https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ThirdPartyAuthSucessFailure&isAuthSuccessful=true
- On Failure: https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ThirdPartyAuthSucessFailure&isAuthSuccessful=false

You can also define your own URLs on the **Auth tokens for eBay** page of the developer site.

The problem is that ebay truncates any url you enter at the first ampersand (&) encountered. This breaks their own accept URL which ends with `&isAuthSuccessful=true`

To fix this all you have to do is encode the ampersand as `%26`. So you need to change their URLs to:

- On Success: https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ThirdPartyAuthSucessFailure%26isAuthSuccessful=true
- On Failure: https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ThirdPartyAuthSucessFailure%26isAuthSuccessful=false

Edit: As you noted, this does not affect whether or not the authorization is actually successful or not, just the message that the user sees. You can also apply this solution to your own URLs too if you don't want to use theirs.

Comment: They seem to have changed the behaviour. For me, the default accept-url did not include the `isAuthSuccessful=true`. Adding it (without url-encoding the ampersand) works for me. The URL I'm using now:
https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ThirdPartyAuthSucessFailure&isAuthSuccessful=true